# PostgreSQL типы таблиц

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Доброго времени суток, у меня такой вопрос, у БД MySQL все понятно имеются типі таблиц такие как :

- MyISAM
- InnoDB
- ARCHIVE
- FEDERATED
- MEMORY
- MERGE
- BLACKHOLE

А в БД PostgreSQL какие есть типы таблиц ? 
есть ли отличия от MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для подключения сторонних движков в PostgreSQL используется механизм FDW (Foreign Data Wrapper)
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/postgres-fdw.html.
Список всех текущих FDW вы можете посмотреть на  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Answer (score 1):

Разбиения по движкам хранения таблиц (таких как MyISAM или InnoDB в MySQL) в postgresql нет. Однако таблицы могут создаваться с флагами TEMPORARY (временные таблицы, автоматически удаляются после завершения сессии) или UNLOGGED (отключенное журналирование - запросы выполняются быстрее, но таблица может повредиться при некорректном завершении работы postgresql, так же такие таблицы не могут реплицироваться стандартными средствами postgresql).